# ParanoidAndroid can't make bluetooth call

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, bluetooth, calls

I recently installed ParanoidAndroid onto my Note 2, and since then I can't make bluetooth calls from my car.  It worked before with the stock ROM, so I know it's the phone that's the problem.  It syncs fine and music plays, just the calls that are the problem.  If I make a call, it goes through but both sides just hear loud white noise.  After a bit of experimentation I found that I am actually hearing myself and the car noises through the speakers, not the other person.  I tried disable all the DSP options in case they were causing but it doesn't make a difference.  It there something obvous I've missed, or is it actually a bug?  If so, how would I go about debugging it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly this problem "actually hearing myself and the car noises through the speakers, not the other person" - ie feedback.

This is with "stable" Paranoid Android release 4.45 on Galaxy Note 2 N7100

I upgraded to beta 4.6 beta 5 - problem is gone now. Hurray! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This certainly sounds like a bug in the ROM. In the first instance you should report it to the system integrator (the person who ported the ROM for that device).

Debugging and developing device drivers is not for the faint-hearted, and it's well beyond the scope of this site!

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be in cyanogenmod for some time. See [this](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-2884) bugdescription.

A fix for MTK-compatible phones was posted [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2414364&page=2)

Comment: Could you add some more information to your answer? Like what the bug description is, and a description of the fix. It is fine to link somewhere else, but a person should be able to actually get the answer to the problem here, not just be linked somewhere else. The main reason is links tend to disappear over time. If those links are dead in the future, your answer tells people nothing.